# Can ping only one way. 2xServer 2012 and Cisco router environment

Tags: networking, router

We are doing test setup of network and currently have 2x Server 2012 and 1x Cisco router and switch.

Both Servers have 2 NICs. 1 connected to the router, and 1 for the LAN.

Router set up done and interfaces set.
The issue atm is that we can't ping from router to the second nci interface(connected to the lan) even though RIP protocol set. But in rip protocol only 1 routing appears for 1 server, when trying to add another one, it just doesn't appear here even though command entered correct.

I might have forgotten to mention something but any help will be appreciated and I will try to help supplying all the answers and info.

Answer (score 0):

Check your route tables on your servers as you are treating them like routers.

Have you read this article from MS [Enable and Configure RIP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469737.aspx) ?

You are most likely missing a default gateway in that table on bother servers.

However, I dont know why you are setting these servers up like this. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here worth mentioning. First off the issue is not RIP and it wouldn't even serve a purpose if you only have one router as it only advertises routes between routers. For the network you have you would need to have each of the servers NICs connected to the router on different subnets.

Server1:
IP: 192.168.0.2
Sbnt: 255.255.255.252
Gwy:192.168.0.1
--attached to RTR1 gi0/0--

Server2:
IP: 192.168.1.2
Sbnt: 255.255.255.252
Gwy:192.168.1.1
--attached to RTR1 gi0/1-

Rtr1:
int gi0/0 
ip add 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.252
no shut

intgi0/1
ip add 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.252
no shut

you can also run the:
sho ip route

command to see which of the configured networks are up and on what interface. Good luck on your project!